# How to update key in nested dict

Tags: dictionary, nested, kivy

I have  a dict that looks like this.

```
  d={   
        "user1": {
            "food": {
                "mleko": "milk",
                "jajko": "egg",
                "jablko": "apple",
                "zaba": "frog"
            },
            "drinks": {
                "kawa": "coffee",
                "sok": "juice",
                "herbata": "tea"
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "random": {},
            "smile": {}
        },
        "user3": {
            "something": {},
            "tree": {}
        }
    }
```

This is my dict for now. It contains user which contains folders in which you can add words. Amount of users, folders and words are dynamic.
Its a part of my app where you can create folders and words and delete them or update.

But question is how can i update key which is also a value in my dict.

Lets say id like to change

```
    "user1": {
        "food": {
            "mleko": "milk",
            "jajko": "egg",
            "jablko": "apple",
            "zaba": "frog"
        },
        "drinks": {
            "kawa": "coffee",
            "sok": "juice",
            "herbata": "tea"
        }
```

to

```
    "user1": {
        "NEW VALUE": {
            "mleko": "milk",
            "jajko": "egg",
            "jablko": "apple",
            "zaba": "frog"
        },
        "SECOND VALUE": {
            "kawa": "coffee",
            "sok": "juice",
            "herbata": "tea"
        }
```

When it comes to change key value and nested dictionaries im completely lost

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```py
d["user1"]["food"] = "NEW_VALUE"
```

Comment: Yes, but it does add new value to 'food' key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    d['user1']['NEW VALUE'] = d['user1']['food']
    d['user1']['SECOND VALUE'] = d['user1']['drinks']
    del d['user1']['food']
    del d['user1']['drinks']
```

You can do a more complex method that preserves the order, but creates a new dictionary:

```
    new_dict = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        if key == 'user1':
            new_dict['user1'] = {}
            for k,v in d['user1'].items():
                if k == 'food':
                    new_dict['user1']['NEW VALUE'] = v
                elif k == 'drinks':
                    new_dict['user1']['SECOND VALUE'] = v
                else:
                    new_dict['user1'][k] = v
        else:
            new_dict[key] = val
    d = new_dict
```

Comment: Yes i was about to edit and say ive found this solution or use POP but i fall asleep. That works but then it will be added as a last item which will change order of displaying those data in my app. Is there any way to switch "index" so it will stay as same place?

Comment: Or maybe you have better idea where or how to store this kind of data so its easier to manipulate them(update/remove/add)

Answer (score 0):

So i have found solution to change key and keep old order of the dict

```
 {"NEW VALUE" if k == 'food' else k:v for k,v in d['user1'].items()}
```